# Altering the Kinetic group childrens array

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Straight forward: How do I change the position of Kinetic.Group children in the array? It is really important for me that I can alter the array and the position of each children.

I tried to add a child with Array.splice on a specific position but the library crashed. So I sticked to the native `.add()` function, took the child from the end of the array and spliced it on first place afterwards:

```
mapTilesContainer.add(image);
var tempChild = mapTilesContainer.children[mapTilesContainer.children.length - 1];
// delete it from the last place
mapTilesContainer.children.splice(mapTilesContainer.children.length - 1, 1);
// add it to the first place
mapTilesContainer.children.splice(0, 0, tempChild);
```

which somehow works, but if I then want to destroy a child regularly with `.destroy()` it crashes again:

```
mapTilesContainer.children[8].destroy();
```

Telling me: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getLayer' of undefined in kinetic.js:2

Adding and destroying without messing with splice works though. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured out that adding the children to the group for rendering as well as pushing them into an own array and destroying them from there works. However if anyone finds a direct way I would appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--- Very uncommon requirement ---

**Is there no workaround in your code instead of messing with kinetic's internal arrays?**

*It's almost always a bad idea to mess with the internals of a library script*

Having said that, I took a quick look at the kinetic's Container.js code.

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/Container.js

This is the internal add child method:

```
add: function(child) {
    var children = this.children;
    this._validateAdd(child);
    child.index = children.length;
    child.parent = this;
    children.push(child);
    this._fire('add', {
        child: child
    });
    // chainable
    return this;
},
```

Note that `child.index` property is set to the position of the child in the array of children.

Properly resetting each child.index is probably your key to manipulating Kinetic's children array.

At line 237 of Container.js is this internal method:

```
_setChildrenIndices: function() {
    var children = this.children, len = children.length;
    for(var n = 0; n < len; n++) {
        children[n].index = n;
    }
},
```

This method might be used by kinetic to reset the indices of a children array.

If you shuffle the children array and then execute your own version of `_setChildrenIndex`, you might not blow up your own app.

**Again:**

*It's almost always a bad idea to mess with the internals of a library script*

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Actually if I decided to implement a list into any library I would have at least implemented an index parameter for the .add() method. The flexibility is just awful.